# Where can I set headers in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I want to set headers as `array('Cache-Control'=>'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate','Pragma'=>'no-cache','Expires'=>'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');` for all my views, currently I'm doing this in all controllers while returning views, like

```
$headers=array('Cache-Control'=>'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate','Pragma'=>'no-cache','Expires'=>'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');

Redirect::to('/',301,$headers);`
```

So instead of writing this for each and every route can it be done in global scope, so that headers are set for every view.

I tried setting headers by creating after filter, but didn't get it to work.

Can anyone tell me where can I set the headers for all my views?

**UPDATE**
One of my view file meta content

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>
```

Now when i use `Redirect::to('/',301,$headers)`
The header in firebug is

```
Cache-Control   max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-cache, no-store, private
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 09 Jul 2013 14:52:08 GMT
Expires Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
```

And when I use `Redirect::to('/');`

The header in firebug is

```
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date    Tue, 09 Jul 2013 14:52:08 GMT
```

Comment: note that 01 Jan 1990 should be a Monday, btw

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways you could do this - all have advantages/disadvantages.

**Option 1 (simple):**
Since the array is just static data - just manually put the headers in your view layouts directly - i.e. dont pass it from anywhere - code it straight in your view.

```
<?php
  //set headers to NOT cache a page
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
  header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
?>
```

**Option 2:** Use [view composers](http://four.laravel.com/docs/responses#view-composers). You can use an App before filter to bind the header to all views in your app.

```
App::before(function($request)  
{
     $headers=array('Cache-Control'=>'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate','Pragma'=>'no-cache','Expires'=>'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');

     View::share('headers', $headers);
});
```

Then just echo out the $headers in your view(s).

Note: you must let the view set your headers - that is why we are 'passing' the header into view for Laravel to handle. If you try and output the header itself from within a filter or something, you'll cause issues.

**Edit Option 3:** I just found out about this - you could try this

```
App::before(function($request)  
{
     Response::header('Cache-Control', 'nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
     Response::header('Pragma', 'no-cache');
     Response::header('Expires', 'Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT');
});
```

Comment: sorry but i didn't get you. What is the use of passing headers to view??

Comment: thats my point - just code the header directly in the view (Option 1). But if for some reason you dont want to do that, you could 'pass' the headers into the view using a view composer.

Comment: Are you talking about meta tags? if yes then i already did that but it is not solving my problem. And about view composer, I don't think that we can set the headers in view composer because headers can only be set using response object and in composer we don't get response object

Comment: "<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">" is a header. When you "set headers" - all that is occuring is that text appears at the top of your html file. So you can either do that with a view composer, or just type it yourself at the top of the file. That is all Laravel does when you set headers - it puts that text at the top of your html file

Comment: Response::header() is not available in L4

Comment: i've editted option 1 for you - just put that at the top of your layouts

Comment: Thank you that did the trick, but instead of putting that in view layout,I ended up putting in after filter

Answer (score 44):

In Laravel 5, using Middleware, creating a new file, modifying an existing file:

New file: **app/Http/Middleware/AddHeaders.php**

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware;

// If Laravel >= 5.2 then delete 'use' and 'implements' of deprecated Middleware interface.
class AddHeaders implements Middleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('header name', 'header value');
        $response->header('another header', 'another value');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Modify existing file **app/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
.
.
.

        'App\Http\Middleware\AddHeaders',
    ];
```

And you're set.

Comment: Works for Laravel 5.6

Comment: This is perfect, worked for Laravel 8

Answer (score 30):

In Laravel 4, this works for me:

In filters.php:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
   $response->headers->set('key','value');
});
```

Like:

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
   $response->headers->set('P3P','CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTR STP IND DEM"');
});
```

Comment: How about in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 12):

In Laravel 5 you can change `/public/index.php` line 55 to set your header for entire app:

```
$response->send();
```

with:

```
$response->header('Content-Type','text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1')->send();
```

for example.

Comment: Where were you one hour ago when I was trying to change the encoding to windows-1252 ? :'(

Comment: I found a new, better method: In /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php add `protected $charset='ISO-8859-1';` after ` public $original;`

Comment: Is it ever a good idea to change core framework files when there is a great system like middlewares available to do this?

Comment: Never change core files, they should be overwritten on the next Laravel update.

Answer (score 10):

For future readers using Laravel 5.x, this can be handled out of the box **without needing to create any custom middleware**.

Laravel has the `response()` helper method, which you can chain headers to very easily.

```
use Response;
// Or possibly: use Illuminate\Http\Response; depending on your aliases used.

// Add a series of headers
return response($content)
    ->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml')
    ->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value');

// Or use withHeaders to pass array of headers to be added
return response($content)
    ->withHeaders([
        'Content-Type' => 'text/xml',
        'X-Header-One' => 'Header Value'
    ]);
```

Read more about it in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses), because it can handle attaching a number of things; `cookies`, `views`, and more.

Answer (score 7):

For Laravel >= 5.2 yet, following @Amarnasan answer , although I used mine for API calls

In Laravel 5, using Middleware, creating a new file, modifying an existing file:

New file: app/Http/Middleware/AddHeaders.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Routing\Redirector;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Applicaion;


class AddHeaders 
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=36000, public');
        //$response->header('another header', 'another value');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Modify existing file app/Kernel.php so that you can use with each specific route

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
.
.
.

        'myHeader' => \App\Http\Middleware\AddHeaders::class,
    ];

And you're set.
```

Then you can use it like so for individual routes or groups

```
$api->get('cars/all', 'MyController@index')->middleware(['myHeader']);;
```

Answer (score 5):

Working on Laravel 4.2.  I'm using filter for this, so in filters.php i have:

```
Route::filter('no-cache',function($route, $request, $response){

    $response->header("Cache-Control","no-cache,no-store, must-revalidate");
    $response->header("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    $response->header("Expires"," Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past

});
```

Than I attach this filter to routes or controllers. Controller attached looks like this for me:

```
public function __construct() {

        $this->beforeFilter('onestep',array('except' => 'getLogin'));
        $this->beforeFilter('csrf',array('on' => 'post'));
        $this->afterFilter("no-cache", ["only"=>"getIndex"]);
    }
```

This filter is attached as afterFilter.

Comment: Can you please explain what does 'onestep' filter do? If possible, please share the 'onestep' filter code snippet.

Comment: Using a route filter to do this gives you the ability to only kill caching on certain routes. Use the `after` hook to set http headers. e.g. `Route::get('/hello', array('after' => 'no-cache', 'uses' => 'HelloController@index'));`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10:

1- `php artisan make:middleware AddMyHeaders`

2- Within handle method of the created middleware:

```
$response = $next($request);
$response->headers->set('HEADER_NAME', 'HEADER_VALUE');
return $response;
```

3- Register the middleware either for routes (`->middleware(AddMyHeaders::class)`) or globally (in `middleware` property of `App\Http\Kernel`). **Note:** Other middlewares might also change headers. If you want your global middleware to have more priority insert it as first item of `middleware` property.