# how to set header details in laravel 5.0 for all views?

Tags: php, laravel-5

i want to assign following code to all views in laravel 5.0.
this code is in php but i want similar like this in laravel 5.0

```
  //set headers to NOT cache a page
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //HTTP 1.1
  header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
```

i could not find solution for cache issue when user clicks on browser back button.

your help would be appreciable

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548569/where-can-i-set-headers-in-laravel

Comment: The below is not applying when you press back button ?

Comment: minus vote for what ?

Answer (score 1):

In your `routes.php` have the below code in the top

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    $response->headers->set('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
    $response->headers->set('Pragma','no-cache');
    $response->headers->set('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
});
```

As you got `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application` error, 
It means you need to install illuminate to your laravel 5.0

Here are the steps :

**Step 1 :**

From your composer `composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"`

**Step 2 :**

In your app.php add the following lines

```
'providers' => [
    ...

    'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
],

'aliases' => [

    ...

    'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
    'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
],
```

Comment: GOT THIS ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::after()

Comment: Have you installed the illuminate in your installation ?

Comment: It seems you didn't install the illuminate in your laravel 5.0, But you probably needs to install. I will update how to do that :)

Comment: Illuminate folder isn't matter, you need to do the above given steps that i have updated in my answer.

Comment: It should be inside your `config` folder

Comment: Both ` 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',` inside `'providers' => [.. ] ` and `'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade', 
    'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',` inside `'aliases' => [ .. ]` ?

Comment: In your composer just navigate to your project folder by `cd cd:/xampp/htdocs/...` and then just run  `composer require "illuminate/html":"5.0.*"` in your composer / command prompt / terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78677/discussion-between-sulthan-allaudeen-and-chetan-patel).