# How to prevent browser back button in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a crm application in laravel 5.2 but I stuck in one problem. I am able to access to previous page although I have properly logged out in Laravel 5.2. How to prevent browser’s back button login after I logged out in Laravel 5.2?

I know this is not a security issue but still I want to prevent user from accessing the previous page using the back button of browser. I used the following solution mentioned in the below URL but it still doesn't work for me. 
https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-logout-and-prevent-back-button/

I am developing my application from scratch as of now. I just used Laravel auth i.e (php artisan make:auth) and found this issue and got stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30118998/prevent-browsers-back-button-login-after-logout-in-laravel-5/64496722

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue. When a user clicks "back" the browser renders the previous page as a cached version.

Here are your 3 options:

1. Don't worry about it. If they were logged in and they saw it previously, they'd expect the same if they go back. However, if they try to navigate anywhere else that has the `auth middleware`, they'll be redirected to the login page anyway.
2. When they log out, redirect them to the login page.
3. Redirect them back to the previous URL, this will fire the `auth middleware` again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation.

Comment: Working for single back button, if I press back button twice, its not working

Answer (score 2):

As everyone said, it is not an issue. But even though you want to prevent it then here is what you can do. In your logout function you, after you call logout method use something like this,

```
return redirect(\URL::previous());
```

I have done it and it solved this issue. Please try this.
Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the response, But it doesn't work. for more clarification I am adding logout function code as well.  
public function logout()    {
        Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();
 
        return redirect(\URL::previous());

    }

Comment: Please try using url()->previous() instead of URL::previous(). Then see if it works. Btw, your logout function looks fine to me

Comment: doesn't work :(  My logout function is under "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php" file. I used php artisan make:auth command for auth.

Comment: You haven't made any controller to handle login logout operations? How are you controlling the routes then? I am confused

Comment: It doesn't work I am still able to access previous page. AS far as controlling routes goes. These are the routes for login and logout. May be I am not getting what you trying to say as I am new in Laravel world. :) 

Route::get('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@showLoginForm');
Route::post('/admin/login','AdminAuth\AuthController@login');   

Route::get('/admin/logout',
            [
                'as'=> 'logouturl',
                'uses'=>'AdminAuth\AuthController@logout'
            ]
);

Comment: That's fine. Your auth controller is fine and routes are fine,too. Try this as last option "return Redirect::back();"  after the  Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->logout();. I don't know why it doesn't work asa I have used all these options in various projects and it still works!

Comment: When I click on "Logout" I got following error.  
"Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Redirect' not found"

Comment: Yeah, so in AuthController, on the top you should use it, like "use Redirect;". Then it will work.

Comment: Error removed but problem remain same. Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: That's fine. As a last resource please refer this official docment, https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication and redirect the user to other url after logout

Comment: Finally I found a solution which is mentioned in below link. However for that I need to change core file which I believe not a good thing to do.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548569/where-can-i-set-headers-in-laravel#answer-31585010

Here is my code 

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/201d2b3bbb3f0db5fedf162c673ec7b0

Comment: I would suggest you not to flush or disable cache as this will significantly decrease the performance and it is not a good thing. So be careful while using the solution. I had that in mind but I would never do that so didn't suggest.

Comment: yeah valid point but unfortunately I don't find any other option as well :(

Comment: But don't go for this solution. Because even if  the user can go to the previous page after logout it is just cache page so don't bother. But have tried redirecting the user to the login page again after logout?

Comment: yes, but doesn't work either and I'll not implement this solution as I am still looking for another one :)

Comment: Hmm..! That's good! Please post the solution once you find it!

Comment: I Found new thing your code "url()->previous()" works but only one time Let me explain you in details. After login I access 1) Customer Details Page 2) Customer Add Page 3) Customer Edit Page and then after I clicked logout and when I click back button I redirect to Login page and then again I click on back button I can access Customer Add Page and Customer Details Page.

Comment: yes its working for me in 5.6    add this code redirect(\URL::previous());   in  AuthenticatesUsers.php in logout function.

Answer (score 0):

solution. Create middleware.

It should look like this.

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware;
 use Closure;

 class HistoryBack
 {
 /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
  * @param \Closure $next
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
  $response = $next($request);

  return $response->header('Cache-Control','nocache, no-store, max-age=0,     must-revalidate')
  ->header('Pragma','no-cache') //HTTP 1.0
  ->header('Expires','Sat, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'); // // Date in the past


     }
    }
```

The following is to register the middleware in the kernel and use them in the routes
regards

excuse my English. I'm using translators to understand. I only speak and understand Spanish and a little English

Comment: Thanks for the response, But I've already tried that solution as I mentioned in my question as well.