# Respond with status code 401 on authentication failure using Laravel and Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm configuring a Laravel project to use Passport token authentication. Everything seems to be working, but when the `auth:api` middleware fails, it responds to the client with a status of `200` and a bunch of HTML in the response body. Instead, I want it to respond with a status of `401`.

I can't find anything in the Laravel Passport source or documentation about doing something like this. I can't even find the source for the middleware.

My test route:

```
Route::get('/protected', function () {
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true
    ]);
})->middleware('auth:api');
```

config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'passport',
        'provider' => 'appUsers',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'appUsers' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\AppUser::class
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can solve it by sending this header with your request.

```
Accept : application/json
```

This will send this message with `401` status code.

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

Comment: I want to add custom code to this JSON response like({
 "error" : 401
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}). How Can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand this answer, can you please complement it showing us how to send that header?

Comment: @Gjaa you can check this answer to learn how to add Header in Laravel Response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548569/where-can-i-set-headers-in-laravel

Comment: If you are working with `Laravel 5.5` and none of that is working and if you remember deleting all type of caches, try running `php artisan config:cache` in all of your servers. Was stuck on it for hours together and only that made it work. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 22):

#### TLDR

You need to make sure the requests include the `Accept: application/json` header.

#### Details

If a user does not authenticate, Laravel will throw an `AuthenticationException`.

This exception is handled by the `render` method in [`Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.4.15/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L107-L120), and will in turn call the the `unauthenticated()` method which is defined in your [`app/Exceptions/Handler.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.4.15/app/Exceptions/Handler.php#L57-L64):

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

As you can see, by default, if the request expects a JSON response, you'll get a 401 with a JSON error body. If the request does not expect JSON, the request is redirected to the login page.

The `expectsJson()` method will return true if your request has either the `Accept: application/json` header, or the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`. The `Accept: application/json` header is more appropriate for api calls, whereas the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header is used for ajax calls.

So, without changing any of your application code, just make sure the requests include the `Accept: application/json` header.

However, if you need to have a different action happen when a user is not authenticated, you can modify this `unauthenticated()` method in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    // return a plain 401 response even when not a json call
    return response('Unauthenticated.', 401);
}
```

Comment: God bless you bro

Comment: If you are working with `Laravel 5.5` and none of that is working and if you remember deleting all type of caches, try running `php artisan config:cache` in all of your servers. Was stuck on it for hours together and only that made it work. Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 10):

In middleware you can return like this:

```
return abort(401);
```

Comment: I didn't write the middleware though. I'm trying to use the middleware (`auth:api`) provided by Larave/Passport.

Comment: You can extend the middleware if you don't want to change to source.

Comment: The `auth` middleware only contains 1 method. Wouldn't I have to just overwrite that method and completely rewrite it?

Comment: Your new middleware should extend Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate.