# Routes protected by auth return 400 error on unauthenticated

Tags: php, laravel, api, exception

On Laravel 5.6, when I call a route protected by the `auth:api` middleware I get a 400 response error instead of the 401 I expect.

api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() {
    //...
}
```

And the Exception handler:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    // If the request wants JSON (AJAX doesn't always want JSON)
    if ($request->wantsJson()) {
        // Define the response
        $response = [
            'errors' => 'Sorry, something went wrong.'
        ];

        // If the app is in debug mode
        if (config('app.debug')) {
            // Add the exception class name, message and stack trace to response
            $response['exception'] = get_class($e); // Reflection might be better here
            $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
            $response['trace'] = $e->getTrace();
        }

        // Default response of 400
        $status = 400;

        // If this exception is an instance of HttpException
        if ($this->isHttpException($e)) {
            // Grab the HTTP status code from the Exception
            $status = $e->getStatusCode();
        }

        // Return a JSON response with the response array and status code
        return response()->json($response, $status);
    }

    // Default to the parent class' implementation of handler
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

The error:

```
{
    "errors": "Sorry, something went wrong.",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthenticationException",
    "message": "Unauthenticated.",
    "trace": [Here's the trace]
}
```

Expected behaviour is visible in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191148/7410951), though the problem is different.

**Why am I getting a 400 with the above instead of a 401 with just the `message`?**

[Full code on GitHub](https://github.com/mwargan/JustBookr).

Answer (score 0):

When the default authentication middleware checks fail, it throws an `AuthenticationException`. You can change how this exception is handled by creating an `unauthenticated` function in your Exception\Handler.php file, see below example.

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception) {
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
    }

    return redirect()->guest('login');
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do that. The error is being caught and sent as JSON, and there is a clause for setting the response code  in my code. It's just not working though :P. As a side node, validation errors and other exceptions are also come with 400 and are formatted as above...

Comment: Where are you setting the response code at the moment?

Comment: `If this exception is an instance of HttpException` note in the first Exception handler, no?

Comment: `AuthenticationException` isn't an instance of HttpException

Comment: Yeah I was thinking it may not be. Does that mean laravel does not set this up natively?

Comment: Just tried it at got `Declaration of App\\Exceptions\\Handler::unauthenticated($request, App\\Exceptions\\AuthenticationException $exception) should be compatible with Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler::unauthenticated($request, Illuminate\\Auth\\AuthenticationException $exception)`

Comment: Add `use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;` with the other `use` lines at the top of the file.

Comment: Yes that should solve it :P! Regardless, I kinda feel this is hack-y. See this answer, thats the behaviour (and notice no setup) that I'm expecting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191148/7410951

Comment: Looking at the default exception handler, if an AuthenticationException is raised, it first calls `prepareException` which overrides the exception with a HttpException setting the status code to 403. You can use the `unauthenticated` function to output as  needed - it's documented functionality and not a hacky workaround.

Comment: I can't figure it out. I've found what you said in the API documentation, but even after adding the function I still get a `400` error with the message Unauthenticated...