# What i need write in SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS, so that I can log in from a different port of the local address?

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, axios

I need to login in my SPA on React, it work on 127.0.0.1:8000 
Laravel working on 127.0.0.1:3000.
When i use axios request, i get error in log in chrome:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

In sanctum.php i added

```
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,localhost:8000,127.0.0.1:3000,::1',
        Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
    ))),
```

In .env i write `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:3000` and try with `SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=127.0.0.1:8000`, but it also didn't work;
In documentation i found information for only domain and subdomain, but i dont work with domains.

Of course I can write in 'cors.php' `'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', 'login']` but i think is bad solutions.

Request code axios:

```
const config={
        headers:{
            accept:'application/json',
            referer:'127.0.0.1:8000/',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
        }
    }
    function fetchCookie(){
        const response = axios.get('http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie')
        const response1 = axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login',loginData,config)
        console.log(response1);
    }
```

Therefore, where and what should I write to make it work for me.

Apologies in advance for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed create a middleware how answered @RaphaelRafatpanah and added in it headers.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://127.0.0.1:3000');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-xsrf-token,Content-Type,withcredentials');
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
        return $response;
    }
```

These headers will solve the initial errors and subsequent.

Answer (score 0):

In your Laravel app, you'll need to set specific HTTP Response headers. These specific headers are generally called CORS headers, because they tell the browser that it's okay to send these HTTP Requests to localhost:8000.

[Where can I set headers in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17548569/1911755)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

This single HTTP Response header should be the minimum you need:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But you can also be more explicit:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I got off the ground, but now I'm getting a different error...